# Complex Regex – is it possible

Tags: jquery, regex

First up, I'm a N00b with Regex it's like a new language that I'm struggling with ATM and looking for some direction.

I have a form that has a serial number field but the fields contents can be one of 3 possible rules.

> **Rule1 :** Length is always 13 Position 1 is always C Positions 2-5 is
>   numeric Position 6 is alpha Position 7-13 is numeric
>
> **Rule2 :** Length is 8 or 9 Position 1-2 is alpha Position 3-8 is numeric
>   Postion 9 is alpha
>
> **Rule3 :**  Length is 9 Position 1-9 is numeric

**My question:** is this of formula achievable inside regex – and sub question: Pointers for where I can look to or expressions I can decipher  ?

Apologies if this is too n00b'esque – RegEx does my head in :)

Comment: Length 8 or 9, then what happens if the length is 8? Is last position alphabet? Or will there be less number?

Comment: I'm sure this is basic, I'm just starting out so looking at (& getting confused) by manuals and examples, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
/^(C\d{4}[a-zA-Z]\d{7}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[a-zA-Z]?|\d{9})$/
```

I suppose that the last alpha is optional in the rule #2

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(C\d{4}[a-zA-Z]\d{7}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[a-zA-Z]?|\d{9})$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    C                        'C'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{7}                    digits (0-9) (7 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]{2}              any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{6}                    digits (0-9) (6 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]?                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{9}                    digits (0-9) (9 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: WOW, thanks so much for this, the detail is awesome and just what I'm looking to learn from. It's getting late here but will let you know how it pans out.

Comment: The "|" character/rule/whatever gave me the "lightbulb" moment. thx.